# Prove using axioms for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

Please help. I have no idea how to go about answering this question.

Question: Prove the following using only the axioms for a vector space and its associated field, explaining which axioms are used at each step of your proof.
$(\forall x \in V)(\forall \lambda \in F)(-\lambda)x=-(\lambda x)=\lambda (-x)$

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I didn't downvote, but beside the fact that this is a no-clue-question, which one should [avoid](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), it should be easy to answer using distributive laws and the definition of an additive inverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that $\;(-\lambda )x=-(\lambda x)$, you simply  have to prove that
$$(-\lambda )x+(\lambda x)=0,$$
and similarly, for the other equality,
$$\lambda(-x )+(\lambda x)=0,$$
using the relevant axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: in any group the inverse is unique; so this also applies to $(V,+,-,0)$.

SO to see $-(\lambda x)$ (the inverse of $\lambda x$) equals $(-\lambda)x$ the latter must also satisfy the inverse property:

$$(-\lambda)x + (\lambda x) = (-\lambda + \lambda)x \text{ (distributivity) } = 0x \text { (in the scalar field) } = 0$$

where the last is usually not an axiom but proven from the the fact that

$$\forall z: (z+z=z) \to z=0$$ in the addition group (by adding $-z$ to both sides and associativity)

$$0x=(0+0)x=0x + 0x \text{ (distributivity) } \text{ so } 0x=0$$.

So it's a mini-series of lemmata leading to it, the main ingredient being the distributivity axiom

$$\forall \lambda,\mu, \forall x: (\lambda+\mu)x=\lambda x + \mu x$$

plus standard facts on the addition Abelian group.

$\lambda(-x)$ also satisfies the property of being inverse to $\lambda x$:

$$\lambda(-x) + \lambda x = \lambda(x + (-x))=\lambda 0 = 0$$

using another distributivity fact and the fact (separately to be shown ) that $$\forall \lambda: \lambda 0=0$$

Comment: Just to be pedantic about terminology, I have the feeling that the point I am going to try to make will somehow be lost on the English sphere of mathematical vocabulary, but nevertheless: it would be natural to speak of *inverses* with respect to *multiplicative operations* and *opposites* with respect to *additive operations*. In other words, to say that $-x$ is the opposite of $x$ and that $t^{-1}$ is the inverse of $t$.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ then maybe also say *negative*, in an additive terminology.

Comment: perhaps an even sounder suggestion, although it is somewhat debatable, since the notion of negative seems to imply a certain comparison with respect to the zero element, in other words an order relation, which is not in general present (at times not even possible) given an additive structure. *Opposite* on the other hand does not have this disadvantage of alluding to something that is not the case, on the contrary it very neatly captures the geometric spirit of say opposite vectors in the plane.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I would call $-A$ the negative of a matrix $A$, despite their being no order.

Comment: of course, to each his own, I am not pleading for the institution of a 'universal nomenclature police force'. Just an exchange of ideas :)